# Insert leading value into numeric column in R

Tags: r

this is likely really simple, but I am unable to find the answer (probably not searching for the right thing...)

How can I insert a lead 0 into a column of numeric values...

Example:

```
values <- c(91414, 80113)
```

Such that they appear like this afterward:

```
091414, 080113
```

Then I would like to transform to a date, and I assume I would just:

```
date <- as.Date(values, format = "%m%d%y")
```

Any and all help appreciated...

Comment: `as.Date(paste0(0, values), format="%m%d%y")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the `lubridate` package for the date transformation:

```
X<-c(91414,80113)
X_date<-mdy(paste("0",as.character(X),sep=""))
X_date

[1] "2014-09-14 UTC" "2013-08-01 UTC"
```

This turns your numeric data to text and add a "0" to the the start of each value, then `mdy` does the date conversion.